# Main actor-isolated property 'name' can not be referenced from a non-isolated autoclosure

Tags: swift

guys!
Is it possible to leave the function "==" in the code and at the same time make the "name" changeable? If I change "let" to "var", I get the following error like in the topic.

```
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class DistanceProfile: Equatable {
    
    let uuid: String
    let name: String
    let authorId: Int
    
    init(uuid: String, name: String, authorId: Int) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.name = name
        self.authorId = authorId
    }
    
    // Equatable
    nonisolated static func == (lhs: DistanceProfile, rhs: DistanceProfile) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid && lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.authorId == rhs.authorId
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the MainActor wrapper, model classes don’t need to be restricted to an actor but should be Sendable. You can make it a struct for easy setup

Comment: Thanks!! 
If you frame this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Unrelated, but if this is really your type (an immutable data type), it should rally be a struct. It's hard to imagine something with this name and structure that would be properly a class.

Comment: It should grow into a real class, but a little later =) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `MainActor` wrapper, model classes don’t need to be restricted to an `actor` but should be `Sendable`. You can make it a `struct` for easy setup.